# Basis for smooth functions between $\Bbb R^d$ and $\Bbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^d \mapsto \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $C^1$ function.  Then can $g$ be written as a sum
$$
g (x_1,..,x_d) = \sum_{k,s=1}^d\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{i_1,\cdots i_d} \left(\prod_{j=1,k_1+...+k_d=n}^d x_{i_j}^{k_j} 
\right)\right]e_{k,s},
$$
where $e_{k,s}$ are the matrices with $1$ in the $k,s^{th}$-coordinate and $0$s elsewhere?

Comment: That would mean $g$ is actually analytic.

Comment: Wouldn't $g$ have codomain $\mathbb{R}$ in this case?

Comment: @lisyarus In that case what would be the correct formulation if I want $g$ to be continuously differentiable?

Comment: @Tom Thanks for pointing that out.  I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. What you wrote is (by definition) an analytic function, not all $C^1$ functions are analytic.

Also there is a problem with your formula: you should take a basis $(e_k)$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of basis $(e_{k,s})$ of  $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$. And your coefficients $a$ depend on $k$.